# window.close() is working only in IE. How to close current tab in firefox window using javascript?

Tags: javascript

window.close() is working only in IE.

How to close current tab in Firefox window using javascript?

Pls help me

Comment: You can only close windows that you also have opened with `window.open`.

Comment: Change you window.close to 

window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close();

Comment: i used your code. But i couldn't close current tab in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say wothout seeing your code, but I came to learn that often the cause of such behaviour could be that the window hasn't been opened by javascript so it doesn't allow it to close.

What you can do to go around this is to add a `window.open` just before your `window.close` statement; have you already tried that?

Comment: <input type="button" onclick="javascript:window.open('', '_self').close();" class="btn" value="Close Window" />

Comment: by the way, not sure if you can combine the two... try `window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();` as @POP suggested above...

Comment: can you see an error in firebug? it would be very useful if you posted that too!